# How to create a new dataframe by sorted data

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I would like to find out the row which meets the condition `RSI < 25`.
However, the result is generated with one data frame. Is it possible to create separate dataframes for any single row?

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

stock='TSLA'

ck_df = wb.DataReader(stock,data_source='yahoo',start='2015-01-01')

rsi_period = 14

chg = ck_df['Close'].diff(1)

gain = chg.mask(chg<0,0)
ck_df['Gain'] = gain

loss = chg.mask(chg>0,0)
ck_df['Loss'] = loss

avg_gain = gain.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
avg_loss = loss.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()

ck_df['Avg Gain'] = avg_gain
ck_df['Avg Loss'] = avg_loss

rs = abs(avg_gain/avg_loss)

rsi = 100-(100/(1+rs))

ck_df['RSI'] = rsi

RSIFactor = ck_df['RSI'] <25

ck_df[RSIFactor]
```

Comment: you might accept and upvote if the answer(s) are helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know at what index the RSI < 25 then just use:

`ck_df[ck_df['RSI'] <25].index`

The result will also be a dataframe. If you insist on making a new one then:

`new_df =  ck_df[ck_df['RSI'] <25].copy()`

Comment: Thanks for helping:)
Is any choice to make it separate.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you want to separate?

Comment: I appreciate your prompt response.
I mean one data frame for one sorted row Therefore, there should be new_df1, new_df2, new_df3, etc..
Thanks

Comment: Each row is a dataframe in itself, so your new_df1 = new_df.iloc[0],new_df2 = new_df.iloc[1]. Although this seems counter intuitive, you can write something about why you want it that way , maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: Actually, i want to find the data as below.
Sort row that RSI <25, then find the highest RSI value of following 14 rows.
Example, we sort row1's RSI is below 25, 
then i want to find the highest RSI value from row 2 to row 15.
As we have different rows that RSI are below 15, we will have a few sets of data.
Therefore, i find the way to store data as various sets
Maybe my logic is worng, it should have a better way to do that.

Comment: As I understand you want to find out the maximum RSI value among the rows where RSI is less than 25 right? Try this : new_df['RSI'].max()

Comment: @JonathanTong, this poses a new question. You should post a new one separately

Answer (score 0):

To split the rows found by @Omkar's solution into separate dataframes you might use this function taken from here: [Pandas: split dataframe into multiple dataframes by number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290757/pandas-split-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-by-number-of-rows/25290795);

```
def split_dataframe_to_chunks(df, n):
    df_len = len(df)
    count = 0
    dfs = []

    while True:
        if count > df_len-1:
            break

        start = count
        count += n
        dfs.append(df.iloc[start : count])
    return dfs
```

With this you get a list of dataframes.