# python pandas - Help in processing large set of data

Tags: python, pandas

Need help in optimizing code below.

code is working for small set of data but not large set.
it is throwing 'unable to allocate array with shape()

code works fine with small file (less than 50 mb) but it failed with large file (more than 200 mb).
the chunck code comes from stackoverflow only.
[Split pandas dataframe in two if it has more than 10 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25290757/split-pandas-dataframe-in-two-if-it-has-more-than-10-rows)

Here is the original txt file

```
id, no, julianDate
123,6683969930867371,24118
123,9.22465322574855E+015,21232
123,9.88635756801637E+015,19219
123,3422437279060279,18110
123,3340444112843298,20124
123,4059401965256193,20131
123,7419046088033512,22331
```

here is the code which is doing:
update id length to 3 if some other length,
convert julian date format YYDDD to YYMM
and jumble the whole df.

```py
import pandas as pd
from os import getcwd, listdir


def single_file(folder):
    # list_of_files = listdir(getcwd())
    for f in listdir(getcwd()):
        if f.endswith('.txt'):
            return f


def convert_file_to_df(file):
    colnames = ['Id', 'no', 'julianDate']
    df = pd.read_csv(file, names=colnames, header=None, converters={'Id': '{:0>3}'.format})
    return df

def convert_no_to_int(df):
    df['no'] = df['no'].astype('int')
    return df


def convert_julian_to_yymm(df, ex_year):
    df['julianDate'] = df['julianDate'].astype('str')
    df['year'] = df['julianDate'].str[:2]
    df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
    df = df.drop(df[df['year'] < ex_year].index)
    df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)
    df['day'] = df['julianDate'].str[2:]
    df['month'] = df['day'].astype(int)
    df['month'] = df['month'] // 30
    df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
    df['yymm'] = df['year'] + df['month']
    df['yymm'] = df['yymm'].astype(int)
    return df

def split_dataframe_to_chunks(df, n):
    df_len = len(df)
    count = 0
    dfs = []

    while True:
        if count > df_len-1:
            break

        start = count
        count += n
        # print('{0} : {1}'.format(start, count))
        dfs.append(df.iloc[start : count])
    return dfs


for f in listdir(getcwd()):
    # print('for loop {}'.format(i))
    if f.endswith('.txt'):
        # print('file if loop {}'.format(i))
        df = convert_file_to_df(f)
        convert_no_to_int(df)
        dfs = split_dataframe_to_chunks(df, 100)
        # loop = 1
        for df in dfs:
            df_data = convert_julian_to_yymm(df, 20)
            small_chunck_df = drop_columns(df_data)
            final_df = pd.concat([final_df, small_chunck_df])
```

here is the data after processing

```
id, no, yymm
123,7623696460219421,2007
123,5638234312228287,2304
123,7285561860395750,2010
123,9232591144713690,2109
123,3214483466634390,2311
123,7443958909235846,2308
123,2479507924021739,2306
123,1477320189903881,2108
```

Comment: share a sample of the original dataframe and your expected output. do a print(df) or df.to_dict() and share the result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: In addition to a [mcve], we’re going to need at least some information on the program’s purpose and functioning.

Comment: You really should not do that concatenation inside the `for`-loop:  `final_df = pd.concat([final_df, small_chunck_df])`. It would be more performant to simply build a list of chunk-specific results, and concat them at the end.

Comment: @AMC updated the message to clear the ask with data requested.

Comment: @NicholasM, I have run small test using df.info to check on memory usage,final_df is increasing gradually only. seems there is not much difference. I am new in python and pandas, can you help me out on how to trace or profiling the code with memory usage etc.

Comment: let me know if anything else needed.